Intermittent Delays in Receiving Teams Channel Messages Notifications via Graph API
I am experiencing intermittent delays in receiving notifications for Teams channel messages through the Microsoft Graph API. I am using Microsoft Graph API to create a subscription to listen to messages in a Teams channel.
Docs here
I can confirm that the subscription is active by making a GET call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions using my access token which returns my subscription details below (details obfuscated):
{
    "id": "xxxxxx-e426-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "resource": "teams/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2/messages?changeType=created,updated,deleted",
    "applicationId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "clientState": null,
    "notificationUrl": "https://example.com/v2/msteams-public/events/teams/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2/messages?changeType=created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationQueryOptions": null,
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://example.com/v2/msteams-public/notifications/teams/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2/messages?changeType=created,updated,deleted",
    "expirationDateTime": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxZ",
    "creatorId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "includeResourceData": true,
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
    "encryptionCertificate": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "notificationUrlAppId": null
}


I am receiving events on my endpoint in local and prod near real time but I am experiencing a delay of 20 to 30 mins in some cases where the message is added in MS Teams but the ping I get is after 20 to 30 mins.
As per the docs here for latency of Teams chat messages, the max expected delay is 1 min
I am unable to find any pattern in these delays for a specific team or for a specific time but on my scale, I am facing this delay from 5% to 10% of messages.
The delays are not tied to any specific team or time, and are making real-time response challenging.
I can also confirm that the endpoint was up and running through out and the server was not down. Hence it could not have been the retry with exponential backoff
I can also confirm that I wasn't throttled as for the notification endpoint on my end, the first middle wear is to respond back to Microsoft with the validation token:
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.validationToken) {
        res.status(200).send(req.query.validationToken);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};

Questions:

Could there be any issues with how I am creating the subscription that might be causing these delays?
Is this latency within expected parameters, or should I be investigating specific configurations on my end?
Are there known issues with the Graph API regarding notification delays that I should be aware of?


This usually means that you probably did not respond to requests in time and were thus sent to slower delivery pipeline.


Subscription creation doesn't matter, but they need to ensure their endpoint is visible to public internet at least to the Microsoft IPs.
30 mins is definitely pretty slow, could you please share the client-REquest-Id and timestamp for received notification so that engineering team can investigate this further. Please share these details at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.
Not really no


Engineering team has looked into the logs and said that you aren't actually responding and abiding by reauthorization requests.
Please read through the doc and follow the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-lifecycle-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Thanks for taking a look into this, the doc you shared, we will be getting the tenantId in the payload but the payload we are getting is missing the tenantId, shared the sample payload with you at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

We confirmed with engineering team that organizationId will always be the tenantId.
